# OpenGL: no light for a simple glut cube

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, light

OpenGL: no light for a simple glut cube

Hi, i'm trying to study lights in opengl and glut but I have problems quite early. I have this code for making a lighted cube in a custom position with custom camera setting:

```
void testApp::draw(){
    static float amb[] =  {0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0};
    static float dif[] =  {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};
    
    float light_diffuse[] = {1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}; 
    float light_position[] = {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}; // i tried a lot of positions here!
    
    // set camera
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 200, 1200, 0,0,0, 0,1,0);

    // set lights
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, amb);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, dif);

    // draw scene
    ofScale(50, 50, 50);
    glPushMatrix();

    glutSolidCube(2);

    // close everything
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING); }
```

I see only a black cube, no light, I think the problem is the light position, I've tried a lot of positions but it does not work: black cube.

Comment: The same problem, tried to texture cube but without any result.

Comment: does this help http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/

Comment: thanks @raj for really good link i didn't know it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are really far away from your cube. Make it smaller and move it closer. Alternatively, change your lighting like this:

```
float light_diffuse[] = {100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0}; 
float light_position[] = {-100.0, 100.0, 1.0, 0.0};
```

You will hardly see any light effects on a cube. Consider using a [teapot](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node89.html).

Comment: ok great, it works perfectly. but i didn't understand why: i had no translations so the cube (now a teapot ^__^) is at 0,0,0 in world coordinate.. light positions should be near this point.. or not?

Comment: The center is at (0,0,0) but the faces are 100 units away from center. Your light wasn't strong enough to affect them.

Comment: @Banthar `light_diffuse` sets the color which is in range `0.0` to `1.0` right? The position change is the key in your answer.